# Django/MySQL LOCK TABLE with transaction.atomic gives savepoint does not exist

Tags: mysql, django

I have activities, which can have multiple 'action' holders, where eacht 'action_holder' can have a dynamic role. For example 'gym-leader', 'student', etc. These roles can be create by the client and are not fixed. Also the 'primary' action_holder_role is denormalized on the model, because otherwise the QuerySet filtering would take to long (more then 2000 activities are loaded on one page, if I would use normal cache instead of the database denormalisatie it would take 20+ seconds instead of 2/3 seconds). For simplicity a lot of fields are taken out in the example. Please note it creates a race condition, which is why the LOCK TABLE is necessary.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField()
    action_holders = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='ActivityUserRole', related_name='realactivities')
    cached_primary_action_holder = models.ForeignKey('ActivityUserRole', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='activity_primary_action_holder_role')
    order = models.IntegerField()

class ActivityUserRole(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # primary for realactivity

 class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My problem is that when I create a new activity, I give the new_action_holders as an argument to the activity and call set_new_action_holders to create the corresponding ActivityUserRoles after saving the new activity (because the ActivityUserRole needs the activity, so it should be saved first).

The get ordering queryset to fill in the order filters on the new_action holder. If I save one activity at a time, it works great. But if I save lets say 3 at the same time. They all get the same order, because the get_ordering_queryset is committed to the database before the save of the first activity is called.

I fixed it by adding:

```
@contextmanager
def lock_table(read=[], write=[]):
    with transaction.atomic():

        cursor = get_connection().cursor()
        lock = 'LOCK TABLES '

        lock = lock + ', '.join([f'{wri._meta.db_table} WRITE' for wri in write] +
                                [f'{rea._meta.db_table} READ' for rea in read])

        # print(lock)
        cursor.execute(lock)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            cursor.execute('UNLOCK TABLES')
            cursor.close()
```

and creating a WRITE lock on Activity, ActivityUserRole and a READ lock on every other related table (there are a lot!) from the moment I call the get_ordering_queryset() function till after the set_new_action_holders function. This works great. The order is now correct. But a) it feels like a hack, and b) I have to READ lock 9 tables and WRITE lock 4 tables, partly because of the post_save signals on ActivityUserRole and many other tables are involved.

And... I cannot use transaction.atomic anymore. If I use it I get a "savepoint does not exist error". I really need transaction.atomic, because Activity should save together with "ExtraInfoActivity", and if one of them fails, I want the transaction to roll back and not have an Activity without the ExtraInfoActivity data.

Is there a better way then LOCK TABLE?

Is there a way to use transaction.atomic() in combination with LOCK TABLE?

Answer (score 1):

`LOCK TABLE` is normally not what you want. It prevents all other writes to those tables, drastically reducing concurrent performance.

Without the view code it's hard to tell you exactly how to structure, but I think you want to use [`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) on some querysets that you read before writing. This will lock just the specific rows.

(And by the way, I maintain the Django-MySQL package with a [`TableLock` class](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locks.html#django_mysql.locks.TableLock) that implements `LOCK TABLES` for those few cases where a table lock makes sense. It's a bit easier to use than your snippet as it finds the table names from the model classes.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am using the Django-MySQL package and it is great. I used it mainly for index hints :) Select_for_update() will not prevent a new object to be created that will fall within the select, does it?

Comment: InnoDB does some "gap locking" to help prevent that. It depends on the queries. I can't remember all the rules - see the MySQL / MariaDB docs.